# How to load list of commandLink in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jsf

I'm trying to load a list of pages according to `User` privilege. 
There's a table in my database storing role, path and the name of page.

My current code is:

```
<h:commandLink action="principal.xhtml?faces-redirect=true">Principal</h:commandLink>
<br/>
<h:commandLink action="manterusuario.xhtml?faces-redirect=true">Usuários</h:commandLink>
<br/>
<h:commandLink action="manterfuncionalidade.xhtml?faces-redirect=true">Funcionalidades</h:commandLink>
<br/>
<h:commandLink action="admin.xhtml?faces-redirect=true">Configurações</h:commandLink>
<hr/>
```

Is there some way to make a for loop do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create an Object and return that from your bean. Lets say your object is like this.

```
public class MenuItem {
    private String action;
    private String text;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

And let say you have a `UserBean` which is binded to your example xhtml (`user.xhtml`) page. And lets say you can create those `MenuItem` from the information you are holding in database.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class UserBean {

    List<MenuItem> menuItemsForRole;

    // This service is responsible for converting database info to menuItem
    // @ManagedProperty("#{menuItemService}") // you may want to inject it
    MenuItemService menuItemService = ...; 

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
       menuItemsForRole = menuItemService.getMenuItemsForRole("MY_USER_ROLE");
    }

    // Getters & Setters & other properties
}
```

And finally in your xhtml file you can do something like this

```
   <ui:repeat var="menuItem" value="#{userBean.menuItemsForRole}" varStatus="status">
    <h:commandLink action="#{menuItem.action}">#{menuItem.title}</h:commandLink>
    <br/>

   </ui:repeat>
```

In order to use ui you must add its namespace to your user.xhtml file.

```
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
```